# Camera not detected in C++ but is detected in QML

Tags: c++, qt, camera, qml

I have a USB camera connected.

The camera is detected in QML and this works:

```
Camera { id: camera}
VideoOutput { 
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: camera
}
```

But in c++, the camera is not in the list:

```
QList<QCameraInfo> cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
foreach (const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo, cameras){
    qDebug() << "*********** Cameras :" << cameraInfo.deviceName();
}
```

This gives no output whatsoever.

What is the difference between QML and C++ ? How can I get access to the camera from C++ ?

EDIT : I've created a brand new project to test it, turns out c++ detects the camera on the new project. Real project is loading a plugin that contain the instance of the class trying to access the Camera, maybe it causes the problem somehow.

EDIT2 : nothing to do with the plugin, after testing, it turns out it doesn't work with QCoreApplication but it does work with QGuiApplication, suggesting QGuiApplication probably set a mediaProvider when CoreApp doesn't

Comment: Where do you call QCameraInfo::availableCameras()? Maybe it requires some sort of Qt initialization before + which platform is this running on?

Comment: @Christian G : It is on Windows, according to the documentation, it shouldn't require anything to initialise it

Comment: You've got some kind of `QApplication` created?

Comment: @velkan : yes of course, I've got a  QCoreApplication loop running. No problem with that

Comment: Is it [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59320), isn't it?

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo : yes this is exactly my problem. Thank you, you can add an answer with this link I'll gladly accept the answer (or I'll post an answer myself if you prefer)

Comment: Yeah, go for the answer yourself. Fine by me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59320

the bug is fixed from version 5.10.1